# Embedded Power Bi Report Server Data without header options

Tags: angular, powerbi, angular8, reportserver

I tried to embed the Power Bi Report Server dashboard but this is showing with header options.
Searching I found that is possible with a cloud Azure subscription.
Do you know if exist any way to do this in Angular 8?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: how are you embedding this in angular 8? Can you show some code?

Comment: I tried to with an iframe tag. Like this   

<iframe width="1000" height="700" src="URL" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>

And here is when I find the problem. 
Searching in google all blogs said that I need a Azure subscription to embedded my dashboard without header tools.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `Power BI Service` and `Power BI Report Server`. With Power BI Report Server you need to add `?rs:embed=true` parameter to the URL used as a source for your iframe. For example, see [Embed a Power BI Report Server report using an iFrame in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed).